# php function for true and false condition

Tags: php, function

I have php function and Iam trying to use this  with true and false condition .

```
function tribe_is_past_event( $event = null ) {

        if ( is_null( $event ) ) {
            global $post;
            $event = $post;
        }
        // Check if event has passed
        $gmt_offset = ( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) >= '0' ) ? ' +' . get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) : ' ' . get_option( 'gmt_offset' );
        $gmt_offset = str_replace( array( '.25', '.5', '.75' ), array( ':15', ':30', ':45' ), $gmt_offset );

        if ( strtotime( tribe_get_end_date( $event, false, 'Y-m-d G:i' ) . $gmt_offset ) <= time() ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
```

This is my function . What I am trying to do if this function is  exist or true then print nothing available else payment option is available

Like this. but this is return only first condition. else condition does not working.

```
<?php 
      if(function_exists('tribe_is_past_event')){
      echo "no option";
      }
       else{?>

                 <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="buy_ticket">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="aatul1031@gmail.com">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php the_title()?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo str_replace("$", "",tribe_get_cost( null, true )) ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?= home_url();?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"     value="<?php global $wp;
echo home_url( $wp->request )?>">
                    <div class="buy_btn">
                    <input type="image" src="" border="0" name="submit" alt="Buy Tickets">
                    </div>
                </form>
       <?php }?>
```

Comment: `function_exists` check if function exists...  You already defined function `tribe_is_past_event`, so first condition is executing, why should it execute `else` condition?

Comment: Seems ELSE part outputs a blank form, it should display ** nothing visible ** when executed. Check the HTML source of the output page to make sure it does not work at all, or it works, but result not visible.

Comment: I suppose you just want to call a function and check it's result: `if (tribe_is_past_event()) {}`

Comment: u_mulder@Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

HI thanks for your kinds support solution is  this . thanks for your support guys

```
<?php 
     if (tribe_is_past_event()){
      echo "no option";
      }
       else{?>

                 <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="buy_ticket">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="aatul1031@gmail.com">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php the_title()?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo str_replace("$", "",tribe_get_cost( null, true )) ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?= home_url();?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"     value="<?php global $wp;
echo home_url( $wp->request )?>">
                    <div class="buy_btn">
                    <input type="image" src="" border="0" name="submit" alt="Buy Tickets">
                    </div>
                </form>
       <?php }?>
```